# Python3.4 : List to CSV

Tags: csv, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert a list to a csv.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

cikList = []

with open('/home/a73nk-xce/PycharmProjects/SP500_list/stockChar/CIK.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
for row in spamreader:
    for eachRow in row:
        eachRow = eachRow.lstrip('0')
        cikList.append(eachRow)

myfile = open('newCIK.csv', 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
wr.writerow(cikList)
```

When running this code I return the following:

```
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
myfile = open('newCIK.csv', 'wb')
```

To:

```
myfile = open('newCIK.csv', 'w')
```